# Ber(X) vs Ber$(\mathbb{E}[X])$

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference

I have a problem that seems to be straight forward, but I can't seem to construct the proof when I think through.

> **Problem:**
>
> Let X be a random variable supported on [0,1], and Ber($p$) be a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p$. Is it true that Ber(X) and Ber$(\mathbb{E}[X])$ have the same distribution?

Knowing that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ for Bernoulli is $p(1)+ (1-p)(0) = p$, a constant, it is obvious that the two will have the same distribution, but how do I show this through a proof?

Comment: Can you clarify what the notation $\mathrm{Ber}(X)$ means? is it something like $p(y|X=x) = \mathrm{Ber}(x)$? So in that case you would draw realisations by generating from a Bernoulli with success rate drawn from the distribution of $X$. Obviously that's potentially different than $\mathrm{Ber}(\mathbb E[X])$ since you could have a realisation that is not equal to the mean.

Comment: @tibL Ber(X) = $p(y|X=x)$ , but will they always have the same distribution on interval [0,1]?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense but so let's imagine that $X$  is Uniform on $[0,1]$, take a draw and get $0.2$. The expected value is $0.5$. Is your question whether $\mathrm{Ber}(0.2) = \mathrm{Ber}(0.5)$ ?

Comment: @tibL I'm looking to prove that on the interval, [0,1] Ber(x) and Ber(E(X)) will have the same distribution, not value.

Comment: Clearly I'm not understanding something in your question so I'll try one more time and then leave it to someone else who may understand it better. $\mathrm{Ber}(0.2)$ is a distribution, $\mathrm{Ber}(0.5)$ is also a distribution. They are not equal.